# testing a curl request with jmeter

Tags: curl, jmeter, httprequest, backendless

I have a curl request and i don't know how to transform it in `jmeter` :

```
curl -H application-id:my-app-id \
     -H secret-key:my-secret-key \
     -H Content-Type:"multipart/form-data" \
     -H application-type:REST \
     --form upload=@/logo.jpg \
     -X POST \
     -v \
     http://localhost:8080/api/v1/files/Photos/logo.jpg
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1: Record the request**

In JMeter:

1. File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create
2. Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder -> Start

In console:

```
 curl -x localhost:8888 -H application-id:my-app-id ......
```

**Option 2: Building Request Manually**

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Server Name: `localhost`
   - Port Number: `8080`
   - Method: `POST`
   - Path: `/api/v1/files/Photos/logo.jpg`
   - Check `Use multipart/form-data` for POST
   - Switch to "Files Upload" tab
   - Click "Add" and provide full path to logo.jpg file, `upload` as Parameter Name and `image.jpg` as MIME Type
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and provide your headers names and values there

---

References:

1. [curl man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)
2. [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
3. [How to Save ‘Loads’ of Time Using JMeter's Template Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

Comment: each time i see a very good simple and depth answers from you . Thank you

Comment: still not working. when i add -x localhost:8888 to my curl i get a fileNotFoundException even that the file exists. ( when i execute my curl without the -x localhost:8888 it works just fine ). 
and the second option not working too : it returns an error telling me the body is empty even that i choose the multipart/form-data and i've put a file to upload.

Comment: It finally worked. The problem was that i must put the file to upload under jmeter/bin directory.

Answer (score 9):

For JMeter 5.1 or higher. There is an easier solution for **creating test plan from curl** just like in Postman

`Tools` → `Import from curl` → Paste your curl into the box → `Create Test Plan`

In some older version, the path can be:

`Help` → `Import from curl` → Paste your curl into the box → `Create Test Plan`

Answer (score 3):

Simple .

1. Create a Thread group .

   > RightClick on TestPlan --> Threads-->Thread Group
2. Add a HTTP Header manager add all Header entries

   > Right Click on Thread Group Created in Step1 --> Add-->ConfigElement-->HTTP Header Manager  and add all[ -H application-id:my-app-id -H secret-key:my-secret-key -H Content-Type:"multipart/form-data" -H application-type:REST]  Note: here you dont have to append -H
3. Add a HTTP sampler

   > Right Click on the ThreadGroup Created in Step1 --> Add-->Sampler-->HTTP Sampler   provide ServerName or IP = local host and Port= 8080  and in Path =/api/v1/files/Photos/logo.jpg   and method = post  and There is add section for send files add accordingly
4. Add a Listener to verify the requests

   > Right Click on ThreadGroup created in Step1 --> Add-->Listener--> View result tree

By the end your Jmeter script should like

```
TestPlan
  ThreadGroup[threads =1 loopcount=1]
    HTTP HeaderManager
    HTTPSAmpler
    View Result Tree
```

Happy Testing .  for more information http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html  if it helps dont forget to click answered.